# Braintree hosted fields integration - edit existing card data

Tags: braintree

I'm using Braintree hosted fields to allow credit card payments, and users can use multiple cards.

How can I allow users to edit existing cards? For example, when a card is renewed by the bank, it keeps the same card number, but the expiration date and CVV change. I want users to be able to edit the expiration date and CVV to keep the card active. Is this possible, or does the user have to enter in a new card from scratch with the same card number?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

Once your customer has their payment method stored in a Vault record you can use their associated payment method token to run a [PaymentMethod.update()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/python) call. Using the payment method update you can change most attributes of the stored method, and you can find a full list of those attributes [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update). When updating actual card information, such as CC number, expiration date, etc. it is recommended that you generate a nonce with the new information rather than entering it manually, but either will work just fine.

Comment: Is it possible to update just the expiration date via hosted fields?  If so does the CC number have to be entered again?

Comment: Nevermind.  Looks like it is not needed.  I just created the hosted fields I wanted to update, tokenized them, and then called paymentMethod.update as said above.

`gateway.paymentMethod.update('card_token', {
     paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTokenize
 })`